# Get screen coordinates of cursor current line EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, coordinates

I want to highlight the line with the cursor on it in an EditText. I have a semi-transparent View which will take place over the line. I need to get a character coordinates on screen in an EditText. (the first and last one of the line) The best I found was getting a text dimensions, but this can't be used for what I want. I tried nothing, because I have no idea where to begin.

Is this possible? 
If not how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be rather easily accomplished by subclassing `EditText`, and inserting the highlight effect in its `onDraw()` method, before everything else is drawn. `EditText`'s `Layout` object can give us the line number from the current cursor position, with which we can get the bounds as a `Rect`. We then draw the highlight rectangle, and call the super method to draw the rest of the `View`.

For example:

```
public class HighlightEditText extends EditText {

    private static final int HIGHLIGHTER_YELLOW = 0x88f3f315;

    private Rect lineBounds;
    private Paint highlightPaint;
    private int lineNumber;
    private boolean lineHighlightEnabled = true;

    public HighlightEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public HighlightEditText(Context context, AttributeSet a) {
        super(context, a);

        lineBounds = new Rect();
        highlightPaint = new Paint();
        highlightPaint.setColor(HIGHLIGHTER_YELLOW);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (lineHighlightEnabled) {
            lineNumber = getLayout().getLineForOffset(getSelectionStart());
            getLineBounds(lineNumber, lineBounds);

            canvas.drawRect(lineBounds, highlightPaint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void setLineHighlightEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        lineHighlightEnabled = enabled;
        invalidate();
    }

    public boolean isLineHighlightEnabled() {
        return lineHighlightEnabled;
    }

    public void setLineHighlightColor(int color) {
        highlightPaint.setColor(color);
        if (lineHighlightEnabled) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int getLineHighlightColor() {
        return highlightPaint.getColor();
    }
}
```

You can include this custom class in your layouts as usual. For example:

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.HighlightEditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" />
```

Please note that if you're using the AppCompat library and its amenities, you should instead `extends AppCompatEditText`, to ensure the tinting and whatnot are handled appropriately.